# Confusion with Git

Tags: git

I am new to Git and get bit confused (Just start to use it today). I have following issue. At work I have git repo and I clone it to my laptop. And at home I clone from my laptop to my Desktop PC.

Work Sever -> git clone -> Laptop -> git clone -> Desktop PC

So after I make some changes to source, I type following command 'git push'. As far as I understand I just push to changes to local repo. Then I try to 'push orgin master' I am getting following error:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 289 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To user_name@host:~/path/to/folder/.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'user_name@host:~/path/to/folder/.git'
```

In my Laptop i did not saw any changes. So what should I do in this case? What is proper way? Can you explain in more details? Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: Do you push to the right server (not your laptop)?

Comment: Did you pull from the remote again befopre trying to push?

Comment: "clone" would've set the origin on your desktop to your laptop. You probably need to adjust the settings in .git/config to change origin to point at the work server.

Comment: I want to push changes to my Laptop. Not for server in my work. Because I cannot reach my server from home it is behind firewall.

Comment: For John Dibling. When I try to pull from my laptop I got a message "Already up-to-date" message

Comment: @JohnDibling Pulling is irrelevant. He's pushing modifications to a branch which is currently checked out on a non-bare repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error, it's giving you clear instructions in plain English.

Git won't push to a repo that has a working directory checked out to the branch you're trying to overwrite, because that is (presumably) somebody else's working directory, and they probably don't want you changing their repo while they're working on it.

Think of it this way: When you're working with Git, you're basically preparing a patch to apply to the currently checked out branch in order to move it from one state, `A`, to another state, `B`. You do this by making changes to the working directory, and staging them with `git add`, and then committing them with `git commit` to produce `B`. If somebody is pushing to your repository and modifying the branch you're on, the state `A` will constantly be changing, and your work will continually be invalidated. You're effectively trying to produce a patch to apply to a moving target. By default, Git refuses to allow you to put yourself into this situation.

You need to either make your laptop's repo a "bare" repo, or check out a different branch on your laptop before pushing, or, as the instructions say, set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to ignore or warn.

The best way of circumventing this situation is to, *from your laptop*, pull changes from your desktop to your laptop, instead of pushing them from your desktop.

Comment: To pull from the desktop to the laptop, you'll have to add it as another remote on the laptop. Remotes are documented here: http://gitref.org/remotes/

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I successfully get changes from my Desktop to my Laptop. I just added another remote branch to my Laptop. And 'git pull desktop master'. Work as I magic. :). How i can train my self to work with git? Can you suggest me some good tutorial? Or some practice way?

Comment: Actually, a better way of circumventing this situation would be to have a separate bare repository (even if it's just a separate shared directory on the desktop or laptop) that both can push to and pull from.  Then there are no worries about overwriting working directories, though there is an extra step involved.

Comment: @Kyralessa Git is designed to pull between peers; that's how it's meant to work best. There is no need to have a 3rd bare repo.

Comment: @meagar, [citation needed].

Comment: @meagar, that says nothing about pulling from peers being "how [Git] is meant to work best."

Comment: @Kyralessa Not going to look up citations; this is common knowledge. Linus built Git to be pull based. Developers send pull requests, lieutenants accept or reject them, and then issue their own pull requests up the chain until eventually Linus *pulls* changes into his repo. This is the fundamental work flow that Git was built to support. There is no need whatsoever to introduce a random 3rd repo to solve this problem.